# VSCODE PHP IntelliSense / Intelephense issues

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I'm working in a PHP Project using Visual Studio Code.

When I install PHP IntelliSense, I can't jump to method definitions by ctrl+click so it's really anoying.

So I've installed PHP Intelephense. Now I can do it without problems, but new issues appear : on some plugins (like Dompdf for example) or even , I have errors in my php files that tells me that some methods are undefined.

Is it possible to have the ctrl+click working on IntelliSense, or Intelephense more powerfull on finding methods declarations ?

For example, Intelephense tells me that "Imagick()" is undefined, but it works perfectly when I use my application...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant display code of PHP extension classes/interfaces because their written by C.
But you can create dummy classes/interfaces for it, fast way - fix dummy code by php.net.